# Eclipse: please check aapt is present at "..\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\aapt.exe"

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt

Recently, I upgraded my android-SDK to **Android M (API 22, MNC Preview)**. After this, every project reported errors when Eclipse was opened.

The error said: 
**"Error executing aapt. please check aapt is present at ..\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\aapt.exe"**.

After checking this *.exe file, I found that "aapt.exe" of **23.0.0_rc1** is at **..\23.0.0_rc1\bin\aapt.exe** not like that of **22.0.1** at **..\22.0.1\aapt.exe**. So, the location of **aapt.exe** is changed, but Eclipse can't realize that.

So, did Android do this on purpose or carelessly? How could I solve this problem in the case of no changing the original file structure?

I use Eclipse as well as Android Studio. So, I want to make sure Android SDK is OK for AS first, then it is Eclipse, So I don't change structure of SDK

Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:**

- My OS is **Windows 7** and **Mac OS X**;
- The **version** of **ADT plugin** for **Eclipse** is **23.0.6**,
  which is up to date by now;
- Also, there is another error reported by a popup window when Eclipse
  starts:
  **Error: Error parsing ...\sdk\system-images\android-22\android-wear\armeabi-v7a\devices.xml
  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: found invalid contents started with an
  element of "d:skin". This child element shouldn't be here.**

Comment: I would bet that problems like this are going to be more and more common.  Google is kicking eclipse to the curb.  You could say this is on-purpose carelessness...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Oh, that's so bad. What do you think of the answer below?

Comment: I am also facing same issue :(

Comment: FWIW, the version that I'm using with Studio and M is .../build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/bin/aapt .  My guess is that the link trick is the best workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Josecash's answer worked like a charm. Here's the solution from that link in english.

It turns out that now the binaries in the build-tools / 23.0.0_rc1 / folder are in a subfolder called bin, so when eclipse will not find them in its new route, the fastest solution is to create a direct link to the binary the folder you are looking eclipse.

**In linux:**

```
$ cd / path / to / sdk /build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/
$ ln -s bin/aapt
```

**In Windows:**
Let the path to the SDK to build-tools \ 23.0.0_rc1 \ bin \ folder Once there click the right mouse button on AAPT -. create direct link, then copy the link to the upper build-tools \ 23.0 folder. 0_rc1 \ and change the name aapt.exe

Then just restart eclipse.

Comment: I'm facing same problem too! But ignoring this message doesn't do any harm. You've to use previous build tools in order to get rid of this message.

Comment: I created a shortcut in parent folder and renamed it but didnt work, is direct link is differ from shortcut in windows? To solve the issue I copy paste the whole content from bin to parent folder and its worked...

Answer (score 1):

Not only aapt tool is missing in the build tools 23.0.0rc1, Eclipse couldn't find other build tools also.

These tools should be located in `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1`, but they are moved to `$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1/bin`.

Move all the executable binaries to a separated directory make the directory tree more structural, but the ADT plugin for eclipse didn't update accordingly.

By creating a symbol links for temporary use.

```
$ cd $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/23.0.0_rc1
$ for f in bin/*;do ln -s $f .;done
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy complete directory "platform-tools" to sdk directory " **\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk " , then restart the eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. Looks like 23.0.0_rc1 is not proper. It does not include aapt.exe. To resolve this issue I removed the 23rc1 (Tools Preview Channel) via Android SDK manager. Now I am using previous build tool.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue -
Just copy the aapt from \Android SDK\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\bin and paste it \Android SDK\build-tools\23.0.0_rc1\ and rename it to aapt.exe
Restart the eclipse and it should be solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Appium and received the error **aapt.exe** not found

Solution is just be careful for Android OS version mentioned correctly in Capabilities as well as automationName as "Appium"

Example - if your Android device OS version is 7.1.1 then mention

cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android 7.1.1");
cap.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");